# Java for-loop condition behaves differently when using length() compared to using an int

Tags: java, for-loop, string-length

I've recently started to learn Java and I've encountered a problem with for-loops. Here's a code snippet:

```
for (int c = 0; c < inputString.nextLine().length(); c++) {
            Random randomIndex = new Random();
            currentString.append(alphabet[randomIndex.nextInt(26)]);
}

System.out.println(currentString.toString());
```

In the code above, I attempt to create a string of random characters that is the same length as a string that the user has inputted. However, the loop only runs once. For example, if I were to input a string of length 4, I would get a one-character string.

If I hard-code the loop condition like this

```
for (int c = 0; c < 4; c++) { // We should have a 4-character string.
            Random randomIndex = new Random();
            currentString.append(alphabet[randomIndex.nextInt(26)]);
}

System.out.println(currentString.toString());
```

I get what I was expecting, a 4-character long string.

Is there some property about the length() method I'm missing? Even running `System.out.println(inputString.nextLine().length())` gives me the expected length of the input string. What's going on?

Comment: nextline consumes the nextline, so the second time it is probably getting something much shorter than you think.

Comment: Please add a problem statement for what you are trying to do here.

Comment: @JeremyKahan when I print ```inputString.nextLine().length()```, I get expected length.

Comment: so instead you could do:  for (int c = inputString.nextLine().length(); c > 0 ; c--) {

Comment: Yes, that seems like a good idea. However, why is the code above not working?

Comment: yes, the first time you would get a good length, but not the second time

Comment: So the length of the input string changes as the loop iterates?

Comment: the condition is evaluated every time through the loop. The call on nextline(), then, keeps getting the nextline(), but you only want to get it once.

Comment: OH! I see what you mean now! Thank you for informing me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was that nextLine() was getting called repeated, each time the condition was tested to see whether to go forward in the for loop. To make the string the same length, you would want to get the length of the next line just once. So the simplest way would be to say:

```
int nextLineLen = inputString.nextLine().length();
for (int c = 0; c < nextLineLen; c++)
```

and do as before.

Answer (score 4):

I'd like to expand on the (correct) accepted answer.

The basic for statement:

```
for ( [ForInit] ; [Expression] ; [ForUpdate] ) Statement
```

is described in the JLS as:

> [**14.14.1. The basic for Statement**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14)
>
> The basic for statement executes some initialization code, then executes an Expression, a Statement, and some update code **repeatedly** until the value of the Expression is false.

i.e. the `Expression`, the `Statement` and the update code are executed multiple times, until the value of `Expression` is `false`.

In your case `Expression` is

```
c < inputString.nextLine().length()
```

and (assuming `inputString` is a `Scanner`), each time that expression is evaluated, it read a new input line, and compares its length to current value of `c`.

This means that if you first input a 4 character `String` and press enter, the condition will be `true`, since `c == 0` and `0 < 4`.

However, the next time the expression is evaluated, a new input line is expected. If you just press enter (which I assume you did, given the output you got), the new input `String` will be an empty `String`, so the condition would be `1 < 0`, which is `false`, and the loop will end outputting a single character `String`.

Note that if instead of pressing enter, you entered 3 more `String`s of at least 4 characters, the loop would have continued and would have produces a 4 character random `String` if you entered an empty `String` (or actually, any `String` of length <= 4) after the 4th iteration.

For example, the following 5 input lines:

```
1234
1234
1234
1234
1234
```

result in an output String of length 4

```
fwpl
```

Of course, the correct solution is to read just one input line, and use its length to determine the number of iterations of the loop:

```
Random randomIndex = new Random();
int length = inputString.nextLine().length();
for (int c = 0; c < length; c++) {
    currentString.append(alphabet[randomIndex.nextInt(26)]);
}
```

Note that I moved the instantiation of the `Random` instance outside the loop, since there's no reason to create a new instance for each iteration of the loop.

```
System.out.println(currentString.toString());
```

Comment: Thanks for this extended answer. It clarifies many things. I'll remember to read the documentation in the future as well!

Answer (score -1):

function nextLine() will return new next line so when the loops run seconds time (c=1): `inputString.nextLine().length()` = 0.

Please, try:

```
int l = inputString.nextLine().length();
for (int c = 0; c < l; c++) { // We should have a 4-character string.
           ....
}
```

Comment: How do you know it will return zero?